# How integrate paypal into vue app using vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am having difficulty to integrate paypal into my web page using vue. I am getting any paypal button. If I use the same code in the vue cli then it's working but when I am using this code in `index.html` using vue cdn then it's not working. I need it to work in `index.html` without using the cli. Can anyone help me please?

HTML code

```
<div id="app">
        <payment-method></payment-method>
</div>
```

Vue js Code

```
<script>

// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('payment-method', {
    template: '<div>'+
    '<div v-if="!paidFor">'+
    '<h1>Buy this Lamp - ${{ product.price }} OBO</h1>'+
    '<p>{{ product.description }}</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div v-if="paidFor">'+
      '<h1>Noice, you bought a beautiful lamp!</h1>'+
    '</div>'+

 '<div ref="paypal"></div>'+
  '</div>',
    data: function() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      paidFor: false,
      product: {
        price: 777.77,
        description: "leg lamp from that one movie",
        img: "./assets/lamp.jpg"
      }
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src ="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client-id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID";
    script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },
  methods: {
    setLoaded: function() {
      this.loaded = true;
      window.paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: this.product.description,
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: this.product.price
                  }
                }
              ]
            });
          },
          onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            this.paidFor = true;
            console.log(order);
          },
          onError: err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }).render(this.$refs.paypal);
    }
  }
  
})


var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: You should be able to load your paypal JavaScript the same way you do you Vue script like `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
` and then `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=client-id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID"></script>` below it. That way you can get rid of the mounted function in your component

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I got it. I am using vue 1 cdn....